# Find where Module is located in Ruby

Tags: ruby, reverse-engineering

this is my first time working with Ruby.
I am currently working with a program that includes a module in the start with "include MODULENAME".

My goal is to "rebuild" this programm to implement it in my own software.
My problem is I can't figure out where this module is coming from.
The program allows the entry of further commands (in Ruby). So my question is, are there any commands i can use to find where this module comes from?

I apreciate any kind of help.

Comment: [`const_source_location`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Module.html#const_source_location-method) can probably help to find its origin.

Comment: So.. with puts ModuleName.constants i tried to get a constant to search for. When writing puts ModuleName.const_source_location('constant') i get an error message -> "undefined method 'const_source_location' for ModulName:Module (NoMethodError)

Comment: `ModuleName` _is_ the constant you want to search for. But you seem to be running an older Ruby version. Can you run the program using Ruby 2.7 or 3.0?

Comment: It seems like the programm im using has ruby version 1.8... I will see if i can update it somehow. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Alternatively, `grep` through the source code (including gems) for `module ModuleName` or just `ModuleName`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.const_source_location(MODULENAME)
```

should tell your where `MODULENAME` is defined. See docs for [`const_source_location`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Module.html#const_source_location-method)

Comment: Hello, same problem here. I get following error message: undefined method `const_source_location' for Object:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: What version of Ruby do you use? `const_source_location` was [introduced to Ruby 2.7](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/93843830198ba436e2ea21a60a11758d47cf521b) about one and a half year ago. Is it possible that you still use an older version of Ruby?

Comment: It seems like the programm im using has ruby version 1.8... I will see if i can update it somehow. Thank you for your help!